# Prevent #ref when cell deleted

Tags: excel, ref, excel-indirect

I'm importing a text file into one sheet, eliminating un-needed lines, while formatting the data on the second sheet.

I have all the formulas on the second sheet set up, referencing cells on the first sheet.

The problem is that after deleting the un-needed lines and the data moves up, the formulas for the deleted lines say #ref.  I want the formulas to use, say Sheet1!B2 no matter what data is there.

I see that Indirect works, so the next question is, how can I copy the Indirect function down a colum of 500 rows with each one having the right reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem recently so just passing along the answer I got. Index functions will help. Below you can see one where the sheet name is reference in cell a1 and it will return the value in cell a2 of the corresponding sheet.

=INDEX(INDIRECT($A1&"!2:2"),COLUMN(A:A))

Comment: Thanks, were you able to copy this formula down a column?

Comment: Yes and it will look to a1,a2,a3 etc as you copy it down.

Comment: So you have the sheet name, in my case "Imported" in cell A1?

Comment: Actually no quotes around imported just as is. Unless the sheet has quotes as well.

Comment: So I have the sheet name referenced.  When I copy, the forumla wants to get a new sheet name.  I only have one sheet with data and my second sheet that has the formula.  I'm wondering if we're talking about acheiving the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I got it.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to reference cells on the same row, including cells on different sheets on the same row, there's an easier way than `Indirect`.

If you write in `A42`:

`=@B:B`

it will look up `B42`.

If you write in `A42`:

`='Sheet 2'!@X:X`

It will look up `X42` on `Sheet 2`.

If you delete the top rows on `Sheet 2`, the formula on `Sheet 1` will point to the new `X42` - no `#REF!` errors.

As long as your formulas in `Sheet 1` just need to reference cells on the same row in `Sheet 2` - so the formula in `'Sheet 1'!A42` might want `'Sheet 2'!X42` but not `'Sheet 2'!X43` - you can just put the column names as inputs into the formula. Otherwise you'll need `Indirect`.

For bonus points, name the columns in `Sheet 2`, so instead of `='Sheet 2'!@X:X` you could write `=cust_DateOfBirth` for example.

Comment: (I use this technique all the time at work. In one sheet, the user pastes exported .csv data. In a second sheet, formulas reference the first sheet and infer things about the exported data, and this sheet is usually hidden. The third sheet presents a summary.)